# How can I change the way a boolean prints in a django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have some django code that prints a BooleanField

it is rendered as True or False, can I change the label to be Agree/Disagree or do I need to write logic for that in the template?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
{{ bool_var|yesno:"Agree,Disagree" }}
```

You can also provide an additional string for the None case. See the docs for [yesno](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) for details.

Comment: Weird ! For me, I had to invert "agree" and "disagree" for it to work

Answer (score 3):

Any of the following may be tried with consistent results:

A.

```
{% if  form.my_bool.value %} 
    {{ "Yes" }} 
{% else %} 
    {{ "No" }} 
{% endif %}
```

B.

```
{{ form.my_bool.value|yesno }}
```

C.

```
{{ form.my_bool.value|yesno:"Yes,No" }}
```

D.

```
{% if form.my_bool.value == True %} Yes {% else %} No {% endif %}
```

Or simply,

```
{{ form.my_bool.value }}    # Here the output will be True or False, as the case may be.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another way if you want to have more options like adding HTML elements and classes

```
{% if var == True %} Yes {% else %} No {% endif %}
```

You can change Yes and No to any html element; an image or span element

Answer (score 1):

If your models have been defined as

```py
class mymodel(models.Model):
    choices=((True, 'Agree'), (False,'Disagree'),(None,"Maybe"))
    attr = models.BooleanField(choices=choices, blank=False, null=True)
```

You can use the built-in method to retrieve the "pretty" string associated with the value by in your template with

```html
{{ object.get_attr_display }}
```

Comment: This is an underrated answer. The question was not only related to solve this in templates and with this method you already have an unambiguous definition on model level, which is also localizable.