# open a div if session set to true

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

views.py

```
def edit_report(request, report_id):

    user = request.user
    if 'report_id' in request.session:
        del request.session['report_id']
    try:
        member = Members.objects.get(member=user)
        account_user = member.user
    except:
        account_user = user.id
    request.session['report_id'] = report_id
    request.session['account_user'] = account_user
    request.session["edit_report"] = True  
    return redirect('method_name')
```

In my application on clicking a button,it takes to edit_report method and if the application is run through that method `request.session["edit_report"]` the session becomes True it is mentioned in views like this `request.session["edit_report"] = True`.I want to check in javascript that if that session is true i want to open a hidden div(make div display inline).How to do it using django.

Comment: Where is your html/javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `django.core.context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting, you'll have an access to the `request` variable in templates.

Then you can assign a js variable to `request.session.edit_report` in the template, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var edit_report = {{ request.session.edit_report|yesno:"true,false" }};
</script>
```

And then use `edit_report` variable in your javascript code.

See also:

- [django request in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702592/django-request-in-template)
- [How can I change the way a boolean prints in a django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845901/how-can-i-change-to-way-a-boolean-prints-in-a-django-template)

Hope that helps.