# Django model.BooleanField value as 0/1

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to receive a string value (`'0'` or `'1'`) when I'm getting `BooleanField`s with `query.values()`
For example if use the next Model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    male = models.BooleanField()
```

And do:

```
print json.dumps(list(Person.objects.values()))
```

I will receive this: `[{"name":"Tom","male":true},{"name":"Lisa","male":false}]`

But I need to have this: `[{"name":"Tom","male":"1"},{"name":"Lisa","male":"0"}]`

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Just modify the content of `list(Person.objects.values())` (which will be a list of dicts) before passing it to `json.dumps()`.

Comment: For templates there is a [yesno filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno): https://stackoverflow.com/a/846159

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution-1 Using `CustomBooleanField`:**

You can subclass the `BooleanField` and add a function [`from_db_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) which returns the value of `True/False` as `1/0`.

```
class CustomBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return int(value) # return 0/1
```

Then in your models, you can use this custom field for `male`.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    male = CustomBooleanField() # use the custom field
```

This will give you value for `male` as `1/0` instead of `True/False` when you get the value from the db

**Solution-2 Using a custom json encoder:**

From the [docs,](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)

> To use a custom [JSONEncoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) subclass (e.g. one that **overrides the
>   `default()` method** to serialize additional types), **specify it with the
>   `cls` kwarg**

**Solution-3 Using list comprehensions:**

Another option is to use [list comprehensions.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

To convert from `True/False` to `1/0`, we will use `int(some_boolean_value)`.

```
objects_list =  list(Person.objects.values())
modified_list = [{"name":x["name"], "male": int(x["male"])} for x in objects_list] # use list comprehension
json.dumps(modified_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, its a normal solution, i know about it. But it's not what i need. Model "Person" can have more fields and this construction will take a lot of space. AND this solution is make one more iteration wich take excess resources. I need the best solution, wich will have a less operations. As example i think to make class wich will be inherited from models.BooleanField and rewrite "from_db_value" method. What do you think about it?

Comment: or second way can be to create custom JSONEncoder and use like this
json.dumps(data, cls=JSONEncoder)

Comment: A custom encoder sounds like a better idea than subclassing the boolean field.

Comment: @TarasProtsenko Yeah fair point. Updated the ans with a custom boolean field which does the same.